# How do I connect to a .sdf local database file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I am using local SQL Server CE database file (`.sdf`) and Entity Framework for my task.

I have created my models and now entity framework should map them to local database.

I have this code in my `Main` method which inserts some data to database(to check):

```
var db = new Context()
var blog = new Blog { Name = 'FirstBlog'};
            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

and this is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="Connection" 
        connectionString="Data source=|DataDirectory|\LocalDB.sdf&quot;" 
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

when I run this, I get this error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

I have tried several connection string but none worked.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested I changed my connection string to be:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="Connection" 
        connectionString="provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data source=|DataDirectory|\LocalDB.sdf&quot;" 
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

but this gives me the following error:

> Some required information is missing from the connection string. The 'metadata' keyword is always required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Install this  [EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact) nuget package and then set your connection  string to somting like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TestDb.sdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Note:**By default entity framework will create TestDb.sdf if it doesn't exsist in
you solutions `\bin\Debug` directory and after deployment it will be in `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming` this directory

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is giving me `No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'. ` error

Comment: you have to install EntityFramework too....just install it and then follow the steps i provided and it should work

Comment: I think it is working but I cannot locate the .sdf file anywhere :( Where does that `DataDirectory` point?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `Server=(localdb)\v11.0` in your connection string to indicate that it is a LocalDB connection.
In addition to that, you also have `&quot` in your connection string that should be removed.

Full details as to how your connection string should look like can be found on this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page.

Examples for connections strings can be found [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/) (Scroll down to

Comment: It is saying `Keyword not supported: 'server'.` :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a Sql Server Compact file, so your provider needs to be one of the System.Data.SqlServerCe providers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyCS" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```